# How can I implement pipe for multiple commands?

Tags: c++, c, linux, operating-system, pipe

I have a task: implement linux shell basics. One of them is execution multiple commands:
ls | sort | grep | ...
How do this?
I read command, split it by '|' character. What is next step?

Comment: There are multiple ways. You can either use the fork-exec combination, or use fifo. Google for linux pipe implementation. You will find some tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read something about `fork`, `pipe` and `exec` syscalls. Anyway I have one really simple shell implementation, just for your inspiration :)

https://github.com/petrbel/NSWI015-unix-programming/tree/master/myshell